# Element edited in contenteditable mode is no more clickable by jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, contenteditable

I generate element in jQuery

```
$(this).append("<p class='textbox' contenteditable='true' />");
```

then write in it some text and if text is on more lines then one, clickable is just first line of text. I need to click on every line not just first. Code for click is

```
 $(".layer-text").on('click', '.textbox', function() {

     alert("XxX");

});
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: So I guess the text flows out of the `p` element? Have you tried adding `overflow:auto` to your `p` element?

Comment: Looks like you should have to post your actual code (such as in some fiddle demo), it works for me this way http://jsfiddle.net/b2QRL/

Comment: Oh yes it was my fault. Thank you. But I have another problem look at this http://jsfiddle.net/b2QRL/2/ why it works that bad? Try to click on first line it works and then try manualy add text to textbox and then click on second or third line. How to repair this?